# Is a sound toggle button relevant today?

Tags: toggle, games, sound

I'm building a game which will be playable on desktop browsers and mobile devices. This game will have sounds for various actions. My question is whether including a sound on/off toggle is nowadays relevant, and especially in the context of a game. Is there a possibility that this is not needed anymore because users know exactly what to do in order to adjust the volume on desktop or mobile, or even completely mute a desktop browser tab in case they need to?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is a substantial number of desktop users who know that they can mute individual browser tabs?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally good practice to keep users inside of the app, anything related to your app should be configured inside of it.

There are many advantages to having ability to adjust the sound inside of your game environment:

- People might want to keep listening a different audio while playing
- People might not know the mute button on browser tabs
- When there are so many tabs open on modern browsers, the tab size shrinks so it's harder to mute from there.

I'd suggest having a adjustable volume bar inside of the game.

Answer (score 2):

When you design anything you should always keep in mind the "new comers", the section of the population that have little to no experience in working with technology, this section is referred to by "the next billion user", these are the people adopting technology in the near future and need more straight forward actions on the screen.

so yes, adding the switch would be helpful and relevant

Answer (score 2):

**There is a difference between toggling sound off for a particular application vs for the whole device.** A user may want to listen to songs on Youtube and play the game on mute. Thus, the sound toggle is a great way to make it visible and clear to the users that just the game can be muted.